# Please help me with the simple tcl code

Tags: linux, tcl

It is a simple code which gives the output when a number is raised to another number.But it is always returning the square of the number and not looping.
Please help guys

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh
proc raise {{base} {pow} args} {
for {set base1 $base} {$pow >= 0} {incr $pow -1} {
set ans [expr $base * $base1 ]
set base $ans
return $ans
}
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use the inbuilt operator to raise another number to a certain power?

Comment: why do you return in the loop?

Comment: Its not about using inbuilt operator. Its about getting the answer to problem brother.

Comment: @karoly horvath- I tried it bothways. Its not working either way even when i return it out of the loop. when i try to return it outside the loop, the terminal is waiting for input. I dont know why and what it is waiting for.

Comment: It's a _really_ good idea to indent your code correctly. An automatic indentation fixer in your editor, while it has problems with some advanced Tcl constructs, would have let you spot this one pretty much immediately. Saves a lot of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are allowing the loop to go through at most 1 iteration. This is because `return` quits the current `proc` (the loop as well automatically).

Fixing that part would give:

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh
proc raise {{base} {pow} args} {
    for {set base1 $base} {$pow >= 0} {incr $pow -1} {
        set ans [expr $base * $base1 ]
        set base $ans
    }
    return $ans
}
```

But.. that doesn't quite give you the answer, does it. The logic of your code is not quite correct. I think it should be:

```
proc raise {base pow} {
    for {set base1 $base} {$pow > 1} {incr pow -1} {
        set ans [expr {$base * $base1}]
        set base $ans
    }
    return $ans
}
```

`incr` takes a *variable name*, not a variable, and you want to iterate until the power is above `1`. If it is 1, then you get the base, hence you don't loop. The last change was to [brace the expressions](http://wiki.tcl.tk/10225). To make the above work for powers of `0` as well, you can use [Peter's `proc`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29880710/1578604).

But all that said, why don't you use the inbuilt operator for this?

```
set ans [expr {$base**$pow}]
```

or even:

```
set ans [expr {pow($base,$pow)}]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The main problem was the incr part. I was not using the inbuilt operator because i was just experimenting with proc. I have just started using tcl tk. So i am just a noob here.  Anyways thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 2):

A slightly less messy solution which gives a correct answer for `$pow` = 0 too:

```
proc raise {base pow} {
    for {set answer 1} {$pow > 0} {incr pow -1} {
        set answer [expr {$answer * $base}]
    }
    return $answer
}
```

It's often useful, when experimenting with code, to be stingy with variables and command invocations: when you're sure that you can't eliminate any more of them, you probably have fairly efficient, readable, and robust code.

Documentation: [expr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm), [for](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/for.htm), [incr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/incr.htm), [proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm), [return](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/return.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm)

Answer (score 1):

just a first-glance-answer: don't you `return` too early?

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh
proc raise {{base} {pow} args} {
  for {set base1 $base} {$pow >= 0} {incr $pow -1} {
    set ans [expr $base * $base1 ]
    set base $ans
  }
  return $ans
}
```